# Traveling to London from Paris as a U.S. Citizen

Tags: visas, uk, us-citizens

I am staying in Paris in a couple of weeks and I booked a day trip to London via EuroStar. Looking around here and the internet I believe I do not need a visa to travel to London from Paris since I will not be staying more than a year. Am I correct on not needing a visa?

Comment: Being in Paris is irrelevant. US Citizens do not need visas to enter the UK for tourism for up to 6 months.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if it mattered or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Visa is required. You'll get an entry stamp that authorizes stay for six months but if all you're doing is a day-trip that's not an issue.

When you return you'll get another entry stamp for the EU, however, unless you have a visa or something for the EU the most you can stay there is 90 days per [About Schengen 90/180 rule](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21461/4868)

Comment: I guess an "entry stamp for the EU" is really an entry stamp for the Schengen area (since he will not have left or entered the EU during travel from France to UK and back)?

Comment: Yah - Schengen would probably be a more accurate word to use since technically the UK is part of the EU but not part of the Schengen zone. And since Switzerland is part of the Schengen Zone but not the EU. But baring those exceptions I think sometimes it can make more sense to say EU to someone who doesn't know the difference between the EU and Schengen Zone and who doesn't even necessarily need to know it.